# Use dotnet build cmd to build several projects into the same output directory

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli

I have a solution that contains about 10 projects, but I need to build a few of them into the same output directory with the same runtime. I managed to build a single project, but when I try to list another one .csproj to cmd it says that I can't specify several of them in one cmd. I can't build an .sln because I don't need all of the projects

```
dotnet build  MyProj\MyProj.csproj MyProj2\MyProj2.csproj --configuration Debug -r win-x64 -p:Platform=x64
```

=

```
error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Whatever the *real* problem is, there's a different way to solve it. You can build all projects in a solution with `dotnet build path\to.sln` for example. You can collect the output of *publishing* multiple projects to a common folder if needed.

Comment: You can create a different solution with just the projects you want. Or you may *not* have to build both projects. If project B refers to project A, building B will also build A if needed

Comment: The situation is that we have a solution that contains different implementations using the same Core project that is also in this solution. Each implementation is dependent on this Core, but it has nothing to do with projects of other implementations in this solution, so I'm looking for a solution to build each implementation separately. P.S. "implementation" is just an abstract name, basically it's just a set of projects

Comment: You're repeating the question without explaining the relations between the two projects or why you want to use the same build folder. You *can* create a separate solution file. An `sln` file is just a file, not the entire folder structure. You *can* just add two `dotnet build` commands to a batch script. If one project depends on another you can build just one of them and .NET will build the other as well.

Comment: Yes you're right. I couldn't reference projects because the main project is a self-contained executable, but other ones no and I was getting an error that this is forbidden.   Creating a separate .sln worked just perfectly, I added to it all the needed projects and built it with a output directory specified and that was that I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Regarding relations - I have a project that is a WPF app, then I have a Core that is used by other projects including this WPF app and some others, no problems here. Then I have a proj with a 3rd party SDK, and after a build it produces a dll that should be placed  near the WPF app exe file to make the SDK work (that is from the official docs). And I have a console utility app that is used for registry editing (I need to run it with admin rights in case there is no required record there), but I can't add this proj as a reference to my WPF app because of the error above about self-contained

Comment: `I couldn't reference projects because the main project is a self-contained executable` That's not true. I've build a lot of self-contained executables that reference a *lot* of other projects. Self-contained executables would be useless if they only worked for projects without references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this (at least directly), as [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) specify the first command argument is a singular project or solution:

> PROJECT | SOLUTION

> The project or solution file to build. If a project or solution file isn't specified, MSBuild searches the current working directory for a file that has a file extension that ends in either proj or sln and uses that file.

You can workaround by:

1. Creating a separate solution file which will include only needed projects
2. Calling command several times with different projects passed
3. Use some CLI automation (basically point 2 but automated)

Comment: Creating a separate solution was the thing I was looking for, thanks!